# PHP encoding what is this type

Tags: php, encoding

i have  php file with this code

```
<?php  echo "\020\000\000\000\000\000\000\000 ?>
```

what type of encoding this is and how to decode it (if possible). please tell anyone.
thank you

Comment: Those are octal-notation C string escapes, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double And there isn't much to decode.

Comment: the file is big i cant paste it all i just the first lines

Comment: Nobody can guess what the remainder is, when you just posted a few null bytes. / Guessing file contents is off-topic anyway.